# What does volitional + と mean?

Tags: grammar, particle-と, volitional-form

For example in this sentence:

> 迷宮内は天井が宿す燐光によって光源に困らない代わりに、**夜になろうと朝を迎えようと**その眩しい光が途切れることはない。

How should I interpret 夜になろうと朝を迎えようと?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 夜になろうと朝を迎えようと
> ≒夜になろうが朝を迎えようが
> ≒夜になっても朝を迎えても (more casual)

「～（よ）うと～（よ）うと」(volitonal form+と+volitonal form+と) means "(regardless of) whether ~~ or ~~".

This ～ようと is like "even if~~", consisting of 意志・推量の助動詞「う・よう」 + 接続助詞「と」.

This usage of と is ＃❷-4-ア on [goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/154670/m0u/%E3%81%A8/):

> 逆接の仮定条件を表す。たとえ…であっても。…ても。㋐意志・推量の助動詞「う」「よう」「まい」などに付く。「何を言われよう―気にしない」「雨が降ろう―風が吹こう―、毎日見回りに出る」