# Omission of する in ようとする when meaning "try to"

Tags: grammar

The aunt is trying to pull a jumper over Harry's head:

> ハリーの頭からかぶせようと、おばさんがやっきになればなるほど服はどんどん小さくなった。
> The harder she tried to pull it over his head the smaller it seemed to become (original text)

I'm struggling to parse this sentence.

I think this part is fine おばさんがやっきになればなるほど服はどんどん小さくなった = "the more desperate the aunt became the smaller the clothes got." But I can't figure out how ハリーの頭からかぶせようと fits into the sentence.

I would have been happy with ハリーの頭からかぶせようと**して**... or ハリーの頭からかぶせようと**したが**... or something like that to means "she **tried** to pull the jumper over Harry's head and/but ...". Is it simply that the する part is omitted (I didn't know you could do that with "try to") or does this part connect to the rest of the sentence in some other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68186/9831 「合格しようと頑張った」とか　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13445/9831 「心を落ち着けようと、オレンジジュースに手を伸ばす。」https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9710/9831 「電話に出ようと立ち上がる」とか

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks. I think I got stuck because I couldn't see how かぶせようと could possibly adverbially modify 小さくなった, but it doesn't does it? It's modifying おばさんがやっきになればなるほど "the more desperate she became **in trying to** pull the jumper over his head ...". Is this the right parsing?

Comment: @user3856370 Yes, that's the correct parsing.